# Logic behind the for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, logic

I understand the above question is not so specific and there are answered threads relating to for loop.

I am new to programming, most of the answered thread are more specific.

My question:

What is the logic behind the for loop and how should be one's approach to write a for loop?

In simple words: How do you and what do you think before writing a for loop?
example: Which variable to initialize, etc

I have problems in understanding for loop, your answers would certainly help budding programmers like me..

Thanks
Peace

Comment: Comparing for-loops to while-loops, you can say, that you use a for-loop when you know how many times you will go through the loop, and use a while-loop when you know a condition for stopping.

Comment: Excellent, should get a good mark for your homework with these.

Comment: By the title, I thought this might be a question regarding theory and best practices, however .. it's _extremely_ hard for me to discern what you are asking. `Which variable to initialize` is what made me close this, We're here to help you if provided with specific examples of a specific problem. That just isn't the case with this question. I'm not locking this, the community is free to disagree with me.

Comment: Hello Tim,
You are absolutely right, The question is vague and i have specified that in the question.

The answers i got completely answered my question and i guess should answer anyone who wishes to learn the logic of "for loop".

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The most common form of a `for` loop is using a new variable as loop counter, and loops from zero up to (but not including) an upper limit.

This loop will go from 0 to 9:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // code here
}
```

You can name your loop variable anything that makes sense. If you don't have a good name for it, the names `i`, `j` and `k` are an old convention for naming variables for small loops.

The point of using `< 10` instead of `<= 9` is that you are looping over ten items. If you are looping over the items in an array, you use the length of the array in the condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < anArray.Length; i++) {
  // access anArray[i]
}
```

There are three statements inside the `for` loop. The *initialiser*, the *loop condition*, and the *post update*. The loop above produces the same code as if you do a loop using a `while`:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
  // code here
  i++;
}
```

You can put anything you like in the three statements in the `for` loop, but you should try to keep close to this common form. That is how a `for` loop is commonly used, and people will easily understand what the loop is doing.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `while (i < 10)`?

Comment: @Jouke van der Maas: Of course it should. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 1):

Loop exists to execute certain block of code (consisting of one or more commands) repeatedly.

You can define how many times that block of code will execute, and inside the loop can use the loop iterator as ordinary local variable.

Whenever I need to run something several times, I'll just use loop - simple as that.

Usually loop iterators don't get special name, `x`, `i` or `n` are just fine.

Those are my two cents given in simple language - if you have more specific question edit your question with it and notify by comment so I can edit my answer with the response.

Answer (score 1):

in programming a for loop is used in places where you have to repeat an action a number of times where number is known.

in `C#` you do it in a syntax like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    //here I am telling C# to run this loop while `i` is less than 10 where I am 
    ////starting i from 0 and incrementing its value after each iteration by 1. so this loop
    //will run 10 times as i reaches from 0 to 9 and will stop as soon as i turns to 10
}
```

you can also use a variable instead of a constant `10`

for example you can ask user to tell how many times he wants to run a loop and store it in a variable `x` then you can run loop `x` times using following code

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i ++)
{
   // if x = 5 loop will run five times
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for-loop` construct is used when we want to execute a block of code a certain number of times. For example, suppose I want to  print the numbers one to five to the Console screen, here is a naive implementation:

```
Console.WriteLine(1);
Console.WriteLine(2);
Console.WriteLine(3);
Console.WriteLine(4);
Console.WriteLine(5);
```

It works fine, but what if the requirements change to say, write the numbers one to one hundred? This is where the `for-loop` helps:

```
int max = 100;

for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Breaking it down:

1. *Initializer*

   `int i = 0;` Sets the variable `i` to 0, which is the number of times the loop has executed.
2. *Condition*

   `i <= max;`  Execute the next iteration if the value of `i` is less-than or equal to `max`.
3. *Step*

   `i++;` Increments the value of `i` after the block of code has been executed, in     preperation for the next iteration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its also worth noting that for loops doesnt have to count a variable up or down, it could do pretty much anything that follow the pattern that @aligray describes:

```
for(MethodThatDoesSomething(); MethodThatReturnsBool(); MethodThatGetsCalledEveryStep()) {  }
```

is a valid for loop for example.

you could even replicate the foreach loop using a for loop:

```
  var i = new int[ ] { 1, 2, 3 };
  for( var enumerator = i.GetEnumerator( ); enumerator.MoveNext( ); ) {
    enumerator.Current.ToString( );
  }
```